# Archive Widget - Show selected Category Post title. Sorted by Year

Tags: sidebar, archives, wp-get-archives

I need to add a widget to the sidebar that shows post titles sorted by year ie:

2011

POST TITLE 1
POST TITLE 2
POST TITLE 3

2010

POST TITLE 1
POST TITLE 2
POST TITLE 3

I was thinking of using the Archive widget to do this, but I dont know how to add the display post title bit and then have the YEAR display as a type of heading for all the posts under that year. This might not be the best way to go...

Any thoughts or feedback would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at 
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-yearly-archive/

Or if you want to code it yourself have a look at wp_get_archives
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

Comment: Hiya Wyck, that is exactly what I  need :) thank you. I spent a fair amount of time looking through  plugins and never came accross this one. It would be nice if the WP extensions section is as easy to browse/ find stuff as the Joomla! one...